# C# Process Start Arguments not working as expected

Tags: c#, process, command-line-arguments

In my code provided, I create a argument string and when I look at the DScmd is correctly formulated.
If I try it in the command line, all is good (run as Admin)
I run it in code and it seems to interpret the argument at each dash (-) as separate paths.
So why the difference in behavior?
Here is the code:

```
if (File.Exists(txtDatPath.Text))
{
    File.Delete(txtDatPath.Text);
}
string qPath = string.Format("\"{0}\"", txtDatPath.Text);
if (rdoOLTP.Checked)
{
    DScmd = "-b8K –d180 -h -L –o32 –t3 -r –w75 -c5G " + qPath;
}
else
{
    DScmd = "–b60K –d60 -h -L –o32 –t1 -s –w100 –c1G " + qPath;
}
//now set up the cmd - ORIGINAL
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
//p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
//p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true; //if True, uses 'ShellExecute'; if false, uses 'CreateProcess'
p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = DScmd;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "diskspd.exe";
p.Start();

// To avoid deadlocks, always read the output stream first and then wait.  
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
txtSdResults.Text = output;
p.Close();
```

The output starts this way - which is incorrect, you can see each dash is being seen as a path:
path: '–b60K'
think time: 0ms
burst size: 0
using software cache
using hardware write cache, writethrough off
performing read test
block size: 65536
using sequential I/O (stride: 65536)
number of outstanding I/O operations: 2
thread stride size: 0
threads per file: 1
using I/O Completion Ports
IO priority: normal
path: '–d60'
think time: 0ms
burst size: 0

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your commandline string does not contain the **ASCII** hyphen character `-` for the options, at least not for some of the options. For example, the hyphen in your `–b60K` option is actually the Unicode character U+2013 (which is also called the "En dash").

I suspect that diskspd.exe only supports the true ASCII hyphen character for options, thus not being able to identify `–b60K` and other options in your argument string because they don't start with the ASCII hyphen character.

Comment: @UnicodelsFun thanks that was it!  Changed the hyphen to `convert.ToChar(45)` and all works. Amazing the little things break all.